# Why i can't install react-router-transition in 1.4.0 version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

```
$ npm install -S react-router-transition@1.4.0
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-to-do@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react-router-dom@5.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-router-dom
npm ERR!   react-router-dom@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-router-dom@"^4.1.1" from react-router-transition@1.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-router-transition
npm ERR!   react-router-transition@"1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-30T16_05_54_608Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if there is a conflict in versions while downloading this version. You could force the download using `--force`, but that could break things silently.

Comment: I used --force and it helped, thanks